# Java - lambda infer type

Tags: java, lambda, functional-interface

I'm playing around with uses of a `FunctionalInterface`. I've seen multiple variations of the following code everywhere:

```
int i = str != null ? Integer.parseInt() : null;
```

I'm looking for the following behaviour:

```
int i = Optional.of(str).ifPresent(Integer::parseInt);
```

But `ifPresent` only accepts a `Supplier` and `Optional` cannot be extended.

I have created the following `FunctionalInterface`:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Do<A, B> {

    default B ifNotNull(A a) {
        return Optional.of(a).isPresent() ? perform(a) : null;
    }

    B perform(A a);
}
```

This allows me to do this:

```
Integer i = ((Do<String, Integer>) Integer::parseInt).ifNotNull(str);
```

One can add more default methods to do things like

```
LocalDateTime date = (Do<String, LocalDateTime> MyDateUtils::toDate).ifValidDate(dateStr);
```

And it reads nicely `Do [my function] and return [function return value] if [my condition] holds true for [my input], otherwise null`.

Why can't the compiler infer the types of `A` (`String` passed to `ifNotNull`) and `B` (`Integer` returned by `parseInt`) when I do the following:

```
Integer i = ((Do) Integer::parseInt).ifNotNull(str);
```

This results in:

> incompatible types: invalid method reference

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For your original problem Optional is powerful enough to deal with nullable values

```
Integer i = Optional.ofNullable(str).map(Integer::parseInt).orElse(null);
```

For date example it would look like

```
Date date = Optional.ofNullable(str).filter(MyDateUtils::isValidDate).map(MyDateUtils::toDate).orElse(null);
```

---

Regarding type error

```
Integer i = ((Do<String, Integer>) Integer::parseInt).ifNotNull(str);
```

Specifying generic arguments for `Do` interface solves a problem. The thing is that just `Do` without specified type arguments means `Do<Object, Object>` and `Integer::parseInt` does not match this interface.

Comment: Ah great, I was not aware of the `map` functionality of `Optional`. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that helped. Take a look at `Optional#flatMap` it is the most universal of `Optional` methods